# Jsoup get element text based on Parent structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsoup, html-table

Long story short; I'm working a website made circa 1995, so it's all tables; tables without ID's or Class names, they are everywhere.

I need to get some text from a particular cell, and after a bit of playing about with `JQuery`, I've managed to build the element hierarchy of it's `Parents()`, and I'm wondering now if I can extract the text from the table cell using `JSoup` based on this information.

For example, I want some text from a `<td>` which has these parents:

```
Parent[0]: [object HTMLTableCellElement] //Actually cell containing text
Parent[1]: [object HTMLTableRowElement] //Row of that cell
Parent[2]: [object HTMLTableSectionElement] //etc..
Parent[3]: [object HTMLTableElement]
Parent[4]: [object HTMLTableCellElement]
Parent[5]: [object HTMLTableRowElement]
Parent[6]: [object HTMLTableSectionElement]
Parent[7]: [object HTMLTableElement]
Parent[8]: [object HTMLDivElement]
Parent[9]: [object HTMLBodyElement]
Parent[10]: [object HTMLHtmlElement]
```

There are about 200 pages structured like this, so I'm hoping to use `JSoup` to extract the text out without too much manual work.

Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks ideaman, I missed that one!

Comment: Can you please post a sample html code?